# Exotic $\mathbb{R}^4$ with a complex structure?

Tags: complex-manifolds, 4-manifolds

Is there an exotic $\mathbb{R}^4$ admitting an integrable almost complex structure?

Comment: What's more: Each small exotic $R^4$ is an open subset of ${\mathbb C}^2$, hence, has the induced complex structure from this embedding.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is a result of Gromov that an open manifold of dimension six or less admits a complex structure if and only if it admits an almost complex structure; see the corollary on page 103 of his book *Partial Differential Relations*. As $\mathbb{R}^4$ is contractible, every exotic $\mathbb{R}^4$ is parallelisable. Therefore, they all admit almost complex structures, and hence complex structures by Gromov's result.

Comment: An alternative argument is to use the earlier result (Hirsch-Smale) that each open parallelizable $n$-dimensional manifold admits an immersion in $R^n$.